# Variable not updating after passing class instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have three classes, like this:

Parent class `VeggiesLevel`

```
public partial class VeggiesLevel : Level
{
    private IEnumerator win_cr()
    {
        this.carrotDied = true;
        yield return CupheadTime.WaitForSeconds(this, 1f);
        this.properties.WinInstantly();
        yield break;
    }
    public bool carrotDied;
}
```

Child class `VeggiesLevelOnion`, this gets destroyed later on. It creates a child `VeggiesLevelOnionHomingHeart`

```
public partial class VeggiesLevelOnion : LevelProperties.Veggies.Entity
{
    private void BashfulAnimComplete()
    {
        this.homingHeartPrefab.CreateRadish().level = this.level;
    }
    public VeggiesLevel level;
}
```

This is the child of the child, `VeggiesLevelOnionHomingHeart`. I want this to be destroyed on `carrotDied` in `VeggiesLevel` turning `true`

```
public partial class VeggiesLevelOnionHomingHeart : AbstractProjectile
{
    private IEnumerator checkDeath_cr()
    {
        while (!this.level.carrotDied)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        this.Death();
        yield break;
    }
    public VeggiesLevel level;
}
```

But no matter what I tried, the boolean never updated when I checked `this.level.carrotDied`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it would be useful to post your `Level`,  `AbstractProjectile` and `Entity` classes then how the `win_cr` and `checkDeath_cr` functions are being called

Comment: @Programmer Posting these is pretty hard, as they are long and theirselves inherit from other classes. What exactly would you want to have/know? `win_cr()` and `checkDeath_cr()` are getting called via `StartCoroutine()` in `Start` of each class, respectively.

Comment: In this case, you could provide a [mcve] by removing from the code presented in the question all logic and dependencies that do not relate or affect the wrong behavior.